# ACCEPT FROM SYSIN in subprogram

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, jcl

Let's say I EXEC a COBOL program from JCL, using a `SYSIN DD` to provide data.

If that program then `CALLs` a COBOL subprogram, and some data is still available from the input, will the subprogram be able to read them using an `ACCEPT` statement?

Or is the SYSIN only accessible from the main program of the run unit invoked from the JCL?

**Edit:** I reckon this would be a bad coding practice. I do not intend to use it, nor am I in need of better alternatives, of which I am aware (such as reading the input device data from the main data and passing it to subprogram(s) through their `LINKAGE`).

Actually I am not writing COBOL code, but studying / processing it, so I'm interested in "corner case" behavior to refine my understanding of COBOL semantics.

Comment: I don't know much about JCL but in general a COBOL main program don't "block" anything - may depends on the way you get the data. If it is plain `ACCEPT` (from SYSIN) each `ACCEPT` will read until the next line break.

As this is SO: What did you tried already? How does the COBOL code actually gets the source?

Comment: There is no "SYSIN DD" clause. DD is a JCL statement, SYSIN is a name which connects the resource specified in the JCL to a program using that name internally. This would be a terrible idea, which would make understanding what your programs were doing much more difficult than necessary. If you want to define multiple "function codes" on your SYSIN, write a program which does the ACCEPT (even better, just READ like normal) and CALL that in multiple places. If the functions are discrete, for certain use a separate DD. Other ways. Just don't try what you've suggested.

Comment: And no, I don't know what it would do. There may be enough that is "special" about SYSIN for it to work, but it is such a bad idea I've never come across anyone who has attempted it.

Comment: I second Bill Woodger's comment.  Usually, you do all input / output in the main program.  You pass data fields to the sub-program, and get calculated fields in return.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your quick answers. Stay assured I would not use such constructs, and that this is not the intent of by question; I edited it accordingly. I'm only interested in understanding COBOL behavior in such circonstances.

Comment: Thanks for precising my phrasing, @BillWoodger. I'd concur with you, but my experience is that if a construct is a bad practice but is not forbidden by a COBOL compiler, someone, somewhere has used it as a "clever hack"...

Comment: Well, you can, as easily as anyone else, test it. If it is not documented to work (it won't be in the COBOL documentation, it'll be "elsewhere") then you are also exposed to changes to the OS/run-time in the future. It would originally been, and remain, a "unit record device", a card-reader. My guess would be it would "work", and even be documented. It's just going to make knowing what is going on a nightmare. If a sub-program ACCEPTs and discovers it is data that it doesn't need, the data is gone.

Comment: So it will only work with a very limited sub-set of possibilities (each program CALLed must always have the data it needs available, and only attempt to access that data) which is a very simple input structure then needlessly complicated.

Comment: To add, I'd not use ACCEPT for data in a Production program. Just define a file in the COBOL program and do the usual OPEN/READ/CLOSE, with error-checking. This does not prevent the data being provided as "card" (`DD *` or `DD DATA`) and then you know for sure, and for ever, that unless you define the file as GLOBAL (for "contained" sub-programs) or EXTERNAL (for separate sub-programs) the behaviour will not be *provide the next record that happens to be lying around*. And, given that, not do it that way. Only do the ACCEPTs in one place, and make them READs.

Comment: Hah. Now I read your updated question. Now I understand this, from your comment: `someone, somewhere has used it as a "clever hack"`. This indicates that you know, but perhaps have not accepted yet, that your task as "understanding what could possibly be going on in any way in its fullness" is entirely impossible. You've picked on what aspect of ACCEPT, but there are at least 98,421 fully-documented idiocies that have been perpetrated in COBOL. You can't pick on one and expect that to have any useful impact.

Comment: I think you are going to have problem forming a question here that is "on topic" if your underlying question is "what all are the ways you can code stupid things, and then do further stupid things so that to the extent tested and under specific circumstances the program 'works'". Try to describe more clearly what your task is, rather than concentrating on an isolated specific, but difficult with the "on topic" thing.

Answer (score 0):

You just can to use the ACCEPT on the main program. If you want to send information, you should use a copy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'd tend to agree with you, but do you have any reference (manual, web page...) to back your claim? We all agreed that doing otherwise would be a bad practice; but this question is about actual runtime behavior in this corner case.